# Dependency injection password different string value

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have create the sql accessor just like

```
public class SQLDataAccessor : ISQLDataAccessor {
    public SQLDataAccessor(string sqlconnectionstring)
    {
        sqlConnectionString = sqlconnectionstring;
    }
}
```

In the single sql connection, it can work as

```
services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor>(sp => new SQLDataAccessor(sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<APIConfiguration>>().Value.DataBase.DefaultDSDN));
```

But when do it in multi connectionstring, I want to special some specify generic will use the other connectionstring, for example

```
services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor>(sp => new SQLDataAccessor(sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<APIConfiguration>>().Value.DataBase.DefaultDSDN));
services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor<store2>>(sp => new SQLDataAccessor(sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<APIConfiguration>>().Value.DataBase.SecondDSDN));
services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor<store3>>(sp => new SQLDataAccessor(sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<APIConfiguration>>().Value.DataBase.ThirdDSDN));
```

Thats mean if not specify the class, it will use default connection string, is that possible to do that ?

Thank you

My work around solution is this, it's similar
In the interface
I create like this

```
public interface ISpecialSQLDataAccessor : ISQLDataAccessor  {}
```

then in the instance , I just

```
public class SQLDataAccessor : ISQLDataAccessor, ISpecialSQLDataAccessor {
    public SQLDataAccessor(string sqlconnectionstring)
    {
        sqlConnectionString = sqlconnectionstring;
    }
}
```

The dependency injection which can do this

```
services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor>(sp => new SQLDataAccessor(sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<APIConfiguration>>().Value.DataBase.DefaultDSDN));
services.AddTransient<ISpecialSQLDataAccessor>(sp => new SQLDataAccessor(sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<APIConfiguration>>().Value.DataBase.SecondDSDN));
```

Comment: It's hard to decipher what you're trying to do. First off what you're doing is an anti pattern by using the serviceprovider to define what should be injected.
Ideally I would dependency inject the APIConfiguration.
You can dependency inject multiple ISQLDataAccessors - but it would really help if you could give a small example of the two different store types.
Also are you sure you can't tackle all of this by just using a [DBContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example code. This is the closest I can come to something that resembles what you're trying to do. But it might even be you're trying to a decorator pattern.

#### The ordinary classes

```
public class ClassExample1
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class ClassExample2
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class ApiConfiguration1
{
    public string Dsdn { get; set; }
}

public class ApiConfiguration2
{
    public string Dsdn { get; set; }
}
```

#### The Data accessor implementation

```cs
public interface ISQLDataAccessor<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> GetData();
}


public class ClassOneAccessor : ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample1>
{
    private readonly ApiConfiguration1 config;

    public ClassOneAccessor(ApiConfiguration1 config)
    {
        this.config = config;
        //More steup
    }

    public List<ClassExample1> GetData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ClassTwoAccessor : ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample2>
{
    private readonly ApiConfiguration2 config;

    public ClassTwoAccessor(ApiConfiguration2 config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public List<ClassExample2> GetData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

#### How the dataaccessors would be used in practice

```cs
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample1> dataAccessor1;
    private readonly ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample2> dataAccessor2;

    public SomeService(ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample1> dataAccessor1, ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample2> dataAccessor2)
    {
        this.dataAccessor1 = dataAccessor1;
        this.dataAccessor2 = dataAccessor2;
    }

    public void GetSomeValues()
    {
        var data = dataAccessor1.GetData();
    }
}
```

#### How everything should be dependency injected

```cs
var apiSettings1 = Configuration.GetSection("ApiConfiguration1").Get<ApiConfiguration1>();
var apiSettings2 = Configuration.GetSection("ApiConfiguration2").Get<ApiConfiguration2>();

services.AddSingleton<ApiConfiguration1>(apiSettings1);
services.AddSingleton<ApiConfiguration2>(apiSettings2);


services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample1>,ClassOneAccessor>();
services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample2>,ClassTwoAccessor>();
```

#### The format of appsettings.json

```json
{
  "ApiConfiguration": {
    "Dsdn": "SomeConnectionstringIGuess"
  },
  "ApiConfiguration2": {
    "Dsdn": "SomeOtherConnectionstringIGuess"
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your explain, base on your example services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample1>,ClassOneAccessor>();
services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample2>,ClassTwoAccessor>(); which can tell if ISQLDataAccessor<ClassExample1> then go for specifc instance
how about services.AddTransient<ISQLDataAccessor,DefaultAccessor>(); ? can do this ?

Comment: That's not possible. Since the interface I showed is generic. It needs to implement a type the interface. Otherwise I suggest using two interfaces where one is generic and the other isn't. Could also just use a direct dependency injection. There are many ways to work around this issue.